# ROS Answers SE migration: TS7400 Board

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im interesting in develop projects with ROS, but i dont know if its possibly to "run" ROS on a TS7400 Technologic System Board, or any of this brand, and how to make this.
Thanks for all the responses.

http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/board-detail.php?product=TS-7400

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42754/ts7400-board/) by [ixion_006](https://answers.ros.org/users/3119/ixion_006/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-08-31**:
Can you provide a link to the hardware and I assume you are planning to use Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has only a 200mhz processor and 32MB Ram..You can run Linux on it and ROS perhaps. But it will be really slow and you need to set it up yourself. I would recommend you buy a Beagleboard or a Raspberry Pi. Those already have a small community with people that use it with ROS. The Raspberry Pi is also very cheap (but harder to source).

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0